# What temperature to froth hemp milk to?

Tags: temperature, steamed-milk, foamed-milk, froth

When frothing cow's milk, if you exceed 150 degrees, you can scald the milk which makes it taste like eggs.

Is there a similar upper temperature for hemp milk?

Answer (score 6):

I would follow the same guidelines as cow milk when using any alternative milk. For one you really just can't taste a liquid that is scalding hot, so you might as well not go so toasty. Other than that - If you think it tastes great, then keep doing that. If it smells less sweet, it probably is less sweet - you just gotta find that perfect sensory sweet spot. I generally aim for about 135F if it's a drink being consumed on site - otherwise about 145 togo.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Just an addition: These degrees are around 55 to 65 Celsius if you are following the global standards.